# Recording and Reproducing Infrared waves in Android

Tags: java, android, audio, wav, infrared

I am new to stack overflow and I am developing an android app which can record and retransmit IR codes via audio input. But i dont know how to do it. Can someone please help me about it. I have built the hardware (An headphone jack with IR Emitter and IR Receiver connected to it) and i can send IR codes by first packing them into .Wav file and then playing that file using AudioTrack but i dont know how to make receiver to work. I want receiver to normally go to recording mode, record every IR code i give and then just repeat it. I have also checked the receiver via WinLIRC it works like a charm. Now its time to implement in android. Currently i am using Aurduino Nano and IR Scrutinizer software to record IR and make a .WAV file but i want this thing in android. There are some apps on playstore like AnyMote which record IR but they use built-in receiver of Android and my hardware uses Audio Input/Output for its function. I have also checked all drivers of ZaZa Remote but none of them showed support for Audio IR Receiver, it can just send IR codes using Audio IR Blaster and that is working very well. Please help me making my receiver to work.

Comment: If you are using the headphone jack then, android probably treats it as audio hardware. You could record audio and try to use MediaRecorder SDK API's and select headphones as an input device. 
You should probably read raw incoming signals and do some signal processing yourself.

Comment: Thanks for reply mate! Finally i got my receiver to work, now my receiver can record audio waves and store in an .wav file. But problem is that it cannot send directly. Reason for this is IRScrutinizer says that it is meaningless signal and also does something that makes the signal meaningfull. Is there any way i can use IR Scrutinizer java files in my project, I tried using them but i got stubs error. Every java file is linked with other java file and stubs are not completing. I just want IR Scrutinizer to take my recorded WAV file and fix it. Is there any way for this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.